# Which position is healthiest for sleep?

Tags: medical-science, sleep

If you believe the internet, there is no healthy way for you to sleep: front, back, side, fetal; they are all going to cause you problems like acid reflux, spinal problems, skin problems, problems with your breasts.

Here is a sample of the [claims](http://www.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/04/19/healthiest.sleep.position/index.html) and I have found [a couple](http://www.healthiertalk.com/how-wrong-sleeping-causes-pain-4152) [of sources](http://www.sharecare.com/question/sleep-on-back-bad-for-you) for sleeping on your back being a problem unless you add a rolled up towel or pillows under your legs.

Is there a sleep position which will give you less (or none at all) medical problems when compared to others?

Unless there are medical concerns is it possible to sleep without assistance (extra pillows, towels, whatever) without risking or causing issues with your health?

Comment: What about sleeping in zero G?

Comment: This will probably vary based on your bone structure, weight, medical conditions, and so on. This is really a case where I suspect the best for you is whatever is comfortable.

Comment: Humans have evolved to sleep lying down, unlike horses which sleep standing up.  Sleeping standing up, or at the wheel of a car, are definitely dangerous to your health.

Comment: @HappySpoon horses do sometimes lie down to sleep, when they feel instinctively safe to do so, such as in a stall. Many animals have the "reflex" of complete muscle relaxation when they fall asleep, as well as the brain disconnecting from the muscles, otherwise they would thrash around when dreaming. The evidence is how dogs and cats twitch a little bit while dreaming: the suppression of movement is not total, but keeps them from waking themselves up (or others sleeping near). Animals snore, which is also evidence of muscle relaxation.